# how to output listeners (View Results Tree) to the main .jtl log?

Tags: jmeter

I have a View Results Tree listener in my HTTP Request sampler, with the "Write results to file" set to `/app/view-results-tree.jtl` and

When I run jmeter in non-gui mode,

```
jmeter -t /app/loadtest.jmx -n -l /app/results.jtl
```

both results.jtl and view-results-tree.jtl are output. In non-gui mode, is it possible to output the listeners data into the main results.jtl log? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can but you won't see any difference between trying to redirect listeners output to the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) and just running JMeter in non-GUI mode with all listeners disabled or deleted.

According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) you should avoid using Listeners, if JMeter's default [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) doesn't contain the metrics you need you can just amend the appropriate [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do this with xml which is what I needed.